# ffmpeg: Queue input is backward in time error

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, command-line-interface

RTMP stream encodes correctly until it beings to loop over the content.
Once the loop starts, the stream stops and the following error messages are spitted out.

I've noticed that this happens when I use both -ss and -stream_loop commands together. -ss is important for my bash script to recover from a crash and -stream_loop is important in the case where I'm short of content.

Command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:40:00 -stream_loop -1 -i output.mp4 -crf 25 -c:v libx264 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*3)" -preset superfast -b:v 4194304 -maxrate 4194304 -minrate 2097152 -bufsize 8388608 -acodec aac -b:a 327680 -f flv <rtmp endpoint>
```

Output:

```
[aac @ 0x7041300] Queue input is backward in time0:04:54.35 bitrate=4285.8kbits/s speed=0.831x [flv @ 0x6ff7780]

Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 294392, current: 5; changing to 294392. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

Comment: Stream loop and input ss don't work well together at present. File a report at trac.ffmpeg.org, if you like.

Comment: Is there a hack around this for my use case?

Comment: Shift `-ss 40` to after `-i`. This will add some start latency.